# Morris.js area graph customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, svg, morris.js

[image: http://uwebsolutions.co.uk/dev/sideways6/images/graph-lg.png]

i need a graph something like this can anyone help me by providing working example on fiddle ?

my current code is:

```
initCharts: function() {
        if (Morris.EventEmitter) {
            // Use Morris.Area instead of Morris.Line
            dashboardMainChart = Morris.Area({
                element: 'sales_statistics',
                padding: 15,
               // behaveLikeLine: false,
               gridEnabled: true,
               // gridLineColor: false,
                axes: true,
                fillOpacity: 0.3,
                data: [{
                    period: '2011 Q1',

                    profit: 0
                }, {
                    period: '2011 Q2',

                    profit: 20
                }, {
                    period: '2011 Q3',

                    profit: 50
                }, {
                    period: '2011 Q4',

                    profit: 40
                }, {
                    period: '2011 Q4',

                    profit: 60
                }],
                lineColors: ['#91C120'],
                xkey: 'period',
                ykeys: ['profit'],
                labels: ['Profit'],
                xLabels:['week'],
                pointSize: 5,
                pointFillColors: ['#FFF'],
                lineWidth: 3,
                hideHover: 'auto',
                resize: true
            });

        }
    }
```

the first problem is i want to use graph target element by class not id because i want to use it multiple times on a single page

second i cant find a way to place days like the image above on xLabels

third i want grids similar with the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use a class instead of an id by passing morris a jQuery or DOM object. If you pass it a string, it must be an id. so you could use a class like this:

```js
element:$('.yourClass'),
```

2. You can use days of the week by using the `xLabelFormat` option, like this:

```js
xLabelFormat: function (x) {
    let day = x.getDay(),
        days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
    return days[day];
}
```

3. You can set the text color of the axis, and adjust the stroke width of the circles, using css

```css
circle{
  stroke-width: 4
}
tspan[dy]{
  stroke: #91C120
}
```

Full working example below:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  let dashboardMainChart = Morris.Line({
    element: 'line-example',
    padding: 15,
    // behaveLikeLine: false,
    gridEnabled: true,
    // gridLineColor: false,
    axes: true,
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
    data: [{
      period: Date.parse('2015-01-01'),
      profit: 0
    }, {
      period: Date.parse('2015-01-02'),
      profit: 20
    }, {
      period: Date.parse('2015-01-03'),
      profit: 50
    }, {
      period: Date.parse('2015-01-04'),
      profit: 40
    }, {
      period: Date.parse('2015-01-05'),
      profit: 60
    }],
    lineColors: ['#91C120'],
    xkey: 'period',
    ykeys: ['profit'],
    labels: ['Profit'],
    xLabels: ['day'],
    pointSize: 5,
    pointFillColors: ['#FFF'],
    pointStrokeColors: ['#91C120'],
    lineWidth: 3,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true,
    xLabelFormat: function(x) {
      day = x.getDay();
      days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
      return days[day];
    }
  });
})
```

```css
circle {
  stroke-width: 4 !important;
}

tspan[dy] {
  stroke: #91C120 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.4.1/morris.min.js" integrity="sha512-UcH7njmQ0j6gF7MPyIgpob6gjNGjLSvfOrujEg4s62riVtueN7H7d8ds5XyXbkTK7ClxG9L+VTb/zly84J9TZA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>Morris.js Line Chart Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="line-example"></div>
</body>

</html>
```